# Can I use isolated power supplies by connecting the input gnd and output gnd together?

Tags: switch-mode-power-supply, isolated

I need a converter module that outputs +15 -15 Volts to feed the opamps. My input voltage is 24V.

I found that UWE1215S-3WR3 for this application.  [UWE1215S-3WR3 datasheet](https://www.mornsun-power.com/html/pdf/UWE1215S-3WR3.html)

[image][image]

---

---

I  know that normally the input and output gnd pins must be completely separated from each other in order to fulfill the isolation function. know that if I connect the gnds of an isolated power supply, the isolated situation will disappear, but I wonder if I will have a problem if I connect the input gnd and the output com pin of a dc dc isolated power supply.Is it okay? can i use it like this?

Comment: Sometimes you have too. But I can't say if you can do it 100% safe because of the negative voltage.

Comment: It's an isolated power supply so you can connect ground however you want. However if you don't need isolation there are more simple ways to get a negative rail

Comment: @Fredled yes  negative output  confuses me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can do it. There is no problem. Obviously, it won't be isolated.

Comment: If it only gave +15 V output, I could be sure of this, but -15 V output confuses me. If there is a system inside the module that gives dc dc positive input and negative output, I do not think there will be a problem, but I do not know what is going on in the background.

Comment: @Electronx why does that make a problem? Of course there is a system inside the module that gives +15V and -15V relative to ground.